# Update list of dictionaries: Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

let's say I have the following data frame table:

df

```
Users    Data_Type
User1    String
User2    Integer
User3    String
```

I have the following sample list which dictionary elements inside it.

my_dicts

```
[{'name': 'User4', 'dtype': 'StringType'},
 {'name': 'User3', 'dtype': 'String'},
 {'name': 'User1', 'dtype': 'Boolean'},
 {'name': 'User2', 'dtype': 'String'}]
```

Based on the above table, I would like to update the above existing list of dictionary`my_dicts`. I would like to get the following result.

```
[{'name': 'User1', 'dtype': 'String'},
 {'name': 'User2', 'dtype': 'Integer'},
 {'name': 'User3', 'dtype': 'String'}]
```

I was trying with this:

```
list_= df['Users'].tolist()
my_new_list= dict(zip((*my_dicts ,), list_))
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3001761

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide how the table is formatted, so I'm assuming this data structure:

```py
updates = [
    ("User1", "String"),
    ("User2", "Integer"),
    ("User3", "String")
]
```

You can update `my_dicts` by going over each element and checking if the `name` key corresponds. If so, overwrite `dtype`.

```py
for (name, dtype) in updates:
    for d in my_dicts:
        if d["name"] == name:
            d["dtype"] = dtype
```

I'm not entirely sure what the behavior should be for deleting rows. If any row in `my_dict` that is not in the new table should automatically be deleted, then what is the point of updating `my_dict`? It sounds like you want to *convert the table to your dict datastructure*.

Comment: Hi, The table is just relational as columns and rows. What do you mean by formatting?

Answer (score -1):

```
newlist = sorted(my_dicts, key=lambda d: d['name'])
```

Comment: This just sorts the array based on the key "name". It doesn't change "dtype" at all. Did you read the question?

Comment: @onkar where the tmp_list is come from?

Comment: @Hiwot renamed the variable. One you have sorted your list, you can now replace desired values